# how to set zend form details in application.ini

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-config

Is there a way to set zend form details in the application config file (application.ini) in Zend Framework. I am looking for a way to move following details to config

- A way to disable form decorators by default
- set element Prefix Path
- default decorator for different element type
- validator path
- plugin details

Comment: yeah, those default decorators are a pain in the **** aren't they! I have ended up with a complete set of my own form_element_* so that I don't have to remove the default decorators every time.

Comment: Seems like storing some of that in your ini file is good, but I suspect you should extend Zend_Form and do most of this set up and use your extended form class for all of your forms.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191216/how-to-remove-all-dtddwrappers-and-labels-on-zend-form-elements/7654193#7654193) which shows an example of extending Zend_Form to easily change the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can check this link from the Zend Manual itself. It talks about using ini files to configure a form:
[Using a Zend_Config Object](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.quickstart.html#zend.form.quickstart.config)

You can add various configurations to your ini file and apply them to the form itself.