# How to have a decorator applied as a default for all forms in Zend_Form?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I need to display form-level errors in my forms (errors that do not belong to one field, but to the whole form submission), with this code:

```php
$form->addError($message);
```

For this to work, I need to add the relevant decorator to my form:

```php
$form->addDecorator('Errors');
```

Fairly easy. The problem is that applying a new decorator causes all default decorators to be removed, thus forcing me to re-apply all of them:

```php
$form->addDecorator('Errors')
     ->addDecorator('FormElements')
     ->addDecorator('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dl', 'class' => 'zend_form'))
     ->addDecorator('Form');
```

This is some redundant code I have in most of my forms. Is it possible to have the `Errors` decorator part of the default decorators, by applying some setting?

I could obviously create an abstract `Form` class to inherit from, but I'm wondering if I'm missing a simpler or more elegant solution.

Comment: Adding the decorator shouldn't reset them, setDecorators would reset them.  I think the elegant easy solution is to extend all of your forms from a base class that extends zend form itself.  This is what I do and I use it to set the form decorators, and the default element decorators, among other things.

Comment: Unfortunately it does: `loadDefaultDecorators()` (called *after* `init()`) adds the default decorators only `if (empty($decorators))`. I'll probably stay with the base class solution.

Comment: One question however:  where do you put these decorators in the base class? In the `init()` method? Then you call `parent::init()` in all child classes?

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191216/how-to-remove-all-dtddwrappers-and-labels-on-zend-form-elements/7654193#7654193) (Scroll down to the "Here is the base class" code block).  The next code block shows how to extend it.  You won't have to call parent::init() in your child classes, just have the normal init method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the loadDefaultDecorators method to create a form class that support errors like:

```
/**
* Form with error decorator included by default 
*/
class ErrorForm extends Zend_Form {

   public function loadDefaultDecorators() {
       $this->addDecorator('Errors');
       $decoratorsWithError = $this->getDecorators();

       //clearing to let the parent do default business
       $this->clearDecorators();
       parent::loadDefaultDecorators();

       //union decorators array so error is first
       $finalDecorators = $decoratorsWithError + $this->getDecorators();

       //finally
       $this->setDecorators($finalDecorators);
       return $this;
    }

}
```

Errors decorator should be the first one to render. 
I think more elegant solution would require Zend_Form refactoring.