# Design forms using Zend Decorators

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, decorator

I am having fight with Zend Form decorators from long but I always forgive as I had no work with them.But now I have, and I want to win. Either I found documentation not so explanatory or I was unable to understand its usage. I  always worked on pure HTML & CSS. Now zend form decorators are quite bit confusing FOR ME.

Does anyone has tutorials, method, or anything by which I can beat decorators so that I get forms as per my designs. In other way I m saying please SPOON-FEED me zend form decorators, so that I dont face problem ever. Some of form design which I may use, or can be taken for example for explaination using zend are available @ http://cssglobe.com/collections/forms/

one more thing : I was sending values to form from controllers. Populate function only populates values. But I want fields which are db specific to get placed in design as I want. So fetching them & passing to form is also of great concern because I don't find a way for achieving it neither by setting a public variable or any internal zend form method.

Comment: See if these answers are any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589603/using-viewscript-decorator-on-nested-subforms-zend-form/7590262#7590262 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191216/how-to-remove-all-dtddwrappers-and-labels-on-zend-form-elements/7654193#7654193

Comment: @drew : U should seriously become a human resource professional, because u really understand what type of designer & developer I m and what I am searching for  . Though I was not expecting such trick to achieve this, but now if this is a way, I m going to use this one. Links to methods http://mwop.net/blog/215-Rendering-Zend_Form-decorators-individually.html & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589603/using-viewscript-decorator-on-nested-subforms-zend-form/7590262#7590262 first answer :)

Answer (score 0):

My personal recommendation is to use the `ViewScript` decorator, which will allow you to output the form into a template.

Comment: how?? If I would be knowing that, why would I have posted question?? I need very clear and easy example to design UI as per my wish.

Comment: Sure...here is a real life example featuring 4 files 1) form.php (the form class) 2) index.php ("controller" file) 3) index.phtml (the main view) 4) form.phtml (the partial used to render the form with ViewScript
http://pastebin.com/iscFgh41

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution @ http://blog.kosev.net/2010/06/tutorial-create-zend-framework-form.html as I want :)

But this was still not complete solution as my requirement were little bit different. So for that I found another solution @ http://paveldubinin.com/2011/04/2-columns-form-with-zend-form/

So mixing the two, I have complete solution for me :)

Comment: New solutions suggested by drew above. Link 1 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589603/using-viewscript-decorator-on-nested-subforms-zend-form/7590262#7590262 &Link 2 : http://mwop.net/blog/215-Rendering-Zend_Form-decorators-individually.html